# jquery use $(location) to open in new window

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click, location

I'm using this code to open a link after a clic on an empty div layer

```
 $("#portal").click(function () {
     $(location).attr('href', 'http://tafidelvalle.com');
 });
```

I need to open it in a new windows but I can't find how make it.

I apreciate any help

Comment: Use the window.open() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
window.open("http://tafidelvalle.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(location)` return the `DOM OBJECT`.

if you have defined `var location = some_selector;` then your code get that DOM and set its `href` attribute.

**Example**

```
var location = "a#location";
$(location).attr('href','http://google.com');
```

what above code do is select anchor link with id of `location` and then set `href` attribute to that link.

Now you want to open new window then you can make use of `window.open();` core javascript function.